# Rails 3.0 method_missing: undefined method in validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

## == Schema Information

## Schema version: 20110111000403

#

## Table name: places

#

## id         :integer         not null, primary key

## name       :string(255)

## latitude   :float

## longitude  :float

## a place can be defined by latitude and longitude or by name

#

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_precence_of :name, :if => lat_long_not_def?

def lat_long_not_def?
  latitude.blank? || longitude.blank?
 end

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :if => :lat_long_not_def?
```

Notice the spelling of 'presence' and the ':' before 'lat_long_not_def?'

Hope it helps.  =)